# Alfonzo is a kangaroo. Each second, he takes a 2-yard hop forward with probability 60% or a 1-yard hop backward with probability 40%.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, expectation

In 15 seconds, I believe that, in expectation, Alfonzo has hopped 15[(2*0.6) + (-1 * 0.4)] = 15*0.8 =  12 yards forward.

How long, in seconds, before Alfonzo takes a hop backwards?

Comment: If we have "success" with probability $p$, and repeat the experiment independently until the first success, then the mean number of trials is $\frac{1}{p}$, in this case $2.5$. The result is intuitively reasonable, and can be proved by summing a series or by a conditioning argument. For details, please see *geometric distribution* on Wikipedia or elsewhere.

Comment: What is the relation between the first sentence and the question?

Comment: Are you asking for the first backward hop, or the first time the total distance covered is backward from the starting point?  In the latter case, all the distances you mention matter, in the former case all that matters is the probability of $0.4$ for a backward hop.  Though of course in the latter case the drift is strongly forward ...

Answer (score 0):

The probability of Alfonzo taking a hop backwards for any given second is 0.4, so the chances of it taking a given time **t** is **$0.4^{t}$**.

I'm not sure if the average distance travelled in 15 seconds is relevant to your question, sorry if I've missed something.

Answer (score 0):

The expected value is the sum of the product of each potential value times its probability.  In this case, the probability of taking n seconds before hoping backwards is $0.4 * 0.6^{n-1}$ because you would go forward (probability 60%) for n-1 seconds before going backwards (40%).

$E[x]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(n*0.4*0.6^{n-1}\right)}=\frac{0.4}{(1-0.6)^2}=2.5$